# parse migration : Server returned error on SASL authentication step: Authentication failed

Tags: mongodb, parse-platform

im trying to *migrate the parse mongodb to self hosted mongodb server (version 3.0.12 on debian 7)*. the firewall is open and i can connect to the mongodb server from my laptop but when i try to migrate the database using parse Migrate App then i get below error
`Server returned error on SASL authentication step: Authentication failed`.
here is what my connection strings look like

```
mongodb://rootuser:S3ecretw0rd@<mongodb-server-ip>:45045/dbtest
```

Answer (score -1):

I've got the solution: I used a plus in my password and because of that it didn't worked.

Comment: Please post this as a comment to the question.. not an answer

Comment: I can't comment (You must have 50 reputation to comment.)